# Extract date, hour from the utc time

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to extract the date & hour from UTC time from the below table in bigquery. I have used timestamp for getting the date or time using the below code. I would like to apply the code for the entire column. How to apply timestamp for the entire column? Can you please assist with it?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP "2020-05-03 16:49:47.583494")
```

My data is like this

[image]

I want result like this:
[image]

Comment: What exact result do you want to see? Why is the title 'minute' and the question about 'hour'?

Comment: @ Felipe, Sorry I need hour and date as two separate columns

Comment: can you show me exactly how you want the result to look?

Comment: @ Felipe, please the table below.
3/05/2020 5AM
4/05/2020 8AM
5/05/2020 12PM
6/05/2020 9AM

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT my_column                                                                   AS original_value,
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_column, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f UTC"), "%e/%m/%Y") AS date,
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_column, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f UTC"), "%l%p")     AS hour
FROM my_table;
```

I am assuming that the column is `VARCHAR`, that's why I am converting it to `DATE`.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo:**

You can check the [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=033af3d3308bbe583c7f7ae596aeb7f8).

---

**Edit:**

My initial thought was that OP wanted the query for MySQL (probably BigQuery is based on that). But it turns out that BigQuery is not based on MySQL. So you can use [FORMAT_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp) in BigQuery, this is how the query would look:

```
SELECT Occurrence                               AS original_value,
       FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%e/%m/%Y", Occurrence) AS date,
       FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%l%p", Occurrence)     AS hour
FROM mytable
```

Comment: @ Mushif, My original value is in timestamp

Comment: @AbdurRahim then you can directly use `DATE_FORMAT` on that.

Comment: @ Mushif, I am using bigquery. It says: Function not found: DATE_FORMAT at [2:8] Learn More about BigQuery SQL Functions.

Comment: Here is my code:SELECT Occurrence                                                                  AS original_value,
       DATE_FORMAT(Occurrence, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f UTC", "%e/%m/%Y") AS date,
       DATE_FORMAT(Occurrence, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f UTC", "%l%p")     AS hour
FROM mytable

Comment: @AbdurRahim I have updated my answer. Please see the **Edit** section.

Comment: @AbdurRahim I'm glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213083/discussion-between-abdur-rahim-and-mushif-ali-nawaz).